# iOS App icon on iTunesConnect not showing

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store-connect

[image]

How do I make the App icon show up here in the iTunesConnect Portal? The App is still in Beta so hasnt been released yet. I have included all the icons in the appIconset and the launchImage in Images.xcassets. I do not see an option to add image for this one though. Will this affect my app when I go to production? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add that icon, you have to have a 1024x1024 image **without transparency**, create a new version of your app on iTunes Connect and in that version add that particular image **on iTunes Connect**.

[image: Here]